# Wrapping manual UItableViewCell deselection in delegate callbacks

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to explain to my colleague that when he does this programatically:

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

he should also "wrap it" in appropriate delegate callbacks. The reason being that in this particular case (deselection was not interactive, but programatic) the **table view controller will not trigger these callbacks** since it is not aware that deselection will happen when it happens.

Here is a snippet from  UITableView class docs:

> **Discussion**
>
> - deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:
>
> Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: or tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: message, nor does it send UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification notifications to observers.

So the proper implementation should look like this:

```
[self tableview:self.tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

[self tableview:self.tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

If the delegate callbacks are not triggered, a promise in the public interface is broken and functionality that depends on these callbacks will break. He says there is no functionality at the moment depending on those callbacks so it is premature optimisation. In my opinion, it is not, as the goal is not breaking the promise.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right because of a one very sensible and important rule:

**[Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)**

> The Principle of Least Astonishment states that the result of
>   performing some operation should be obvious, consistent, and
>   predictable, based upon the name of the operation and other clues.

If someone new in the project will have to implement some new feature in the future, he will be **astonished** when his `UITableView` will deselect itself but not call the delegate methods, because that's the **obvious, consistent and predictable behaviour.** It's the **promise** you speak of.

That's a great example of breaking the rule of least astonishment.

Now imagine that you have 100 methods/objects in a project that are unpredictable that way. Horror, right? That's why this this easy principle is very important to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of "promise" makes your question seem rather philosophical.

You as developer have to decide for yourself or in your team, if it is really necessary to perform delegate calls manually in such particular situations.

There's surely a reason why the tableview does not call its delegate methods automatically, as there obviously is a big difference whether the **user** actually selects/deselects a cell himself or whether you do that programatically. There are plenty scenarios where you would like to call methods like `deselectRowAtIndexPath` or other matchable, where you can rely on the fact that the referring object's delegate methods *won't* be called.

So in my opinion there is no such thing as a *promise* in that case or a obligation to wrap your delegate calls, otherwise Apple probably would have changed the behavior of these particular methods, wouldn't they?

You even say that there is no functionality depending on this calls in your project, so why bother? :)

Comment: By "promise" I mean a class is declaring something publicly. You expect that declaration to be true otherwise everything would break. It is declaring publicly that it implements the UITableViewDelegate protocol. Methods in that protocol are documented and the documentation says exactly when they are triggered. The wording of the documentation is unambiguous. It is not mentioning ANY exception. That means IMO the behaviour (methods will be called) has to be there all the time.

Comment: @croX Imagine that you just entered a project and there's a `TextEdit` control wrapped with custom behaviour. You want to do something, when the edit control text changes. The developer that created this form fetches a string from the server and manually puts it into the control, without calling `didChange` delegate, because he didn't need it at the time. ----- You won't know what's happening, you will be surprised and waste some time. Now imagine that the same developer did the same thing a hundreds of times in the same project. Do you still think if it's up to the developer to decide ?

Comment: To be clear, I did not say, that this approach is wrong or even foolish. What I wanted to point out is that in my opinion it is not an obligation to wrap delegate calls, as there are scenarios where —from the developer side— it is a relief that delegate calls won't be sent. Still, it is a valid design approach which can be considered to be used in your particular team. Of course you have to decide as team @michal.ciurus. And believe me, I could tell you another x-examples where you wouldn't want the behavior you just described. It is a matter of taste and depends on the project and its members

Comment: Yeah, it might be a matter of taste so we can't give a definitive answer. I'm all for following the "rule of least astonishment" and make the program as consistent and predictable as possible.